# Issue with global import of AngularFireAuthModule

Tags: typescript, ionic3

### Question

Why am I getting the "No provider for AngularFireAuth!" error when my imports appear to be correct?

I have a `LoginPage` that uses a `app-login-form` component in the html.  This component uses my `AuthService` to authenticate the user.  The `AuthService` uses `AngularFireAuth` to do the things. This all seems pretty simple but the issue with the import is there.

If I comment out the `AngularFireAuth` in `AuthService` the issue goes away.  I was under the impression that importing `AngularFireModule` in the `app.module.ts` would globally import this.  I've also tried to add `AngularFireAuth` to the `providers` in `app.module.ts` with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { FIREBASE_CONFIG } from './app.firebase.config';

import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { AuthService } from '../providers/auth/auth.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG),
    AngularFireAuthModule // IMPORTED GLOBALLY HERE!
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    AuthService // MY SERVICE HERE!
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### LoginFormComponent

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { UserAccount } from '../../models/user-account/user-account.interface';
import { LoginResponse } from '../../models/login/login-response.interface';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-form',
  templateUrl: 'login-form.component.html'
})
export class LoginFormComponent {

  userAccount = {} as UserAccount;

  @Output()
  loginStatus: EventEmitter<LoginResponse>;

  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) {
    this.loginStatus = new EventEmitter<LoginResponse>();
  }

  async login() {
    const loginResponse = await this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.userAccount);
    this.loginStatus.emit(loginResponse);
  }

  navigateToRegisterPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push('RegisterPage');
  }

}
```

#### AuthService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularFire2/auth';
import { UserAccount } from '../../models/user-account/user-account.interface';
import { LoginResponse } from '../../models/login/login-response.interface';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {

  }

  async signInWithEmailAndPassword(userAccount: UserAccount) {
    try {
      return <LoginResponse>{
        result: await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userAccount.email, userAccount.password)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return <LoginResponse>{
        error: e
      }
    }
  }

  async createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userAccount: UserAccount){
    try {
      return <LoginResponse>{
        result: await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userAccount.email, userAccount.password)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return <LoginResponse>{
        error: e
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to do _both_ `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG),
    AngularFireAuthModule // IMPORTED GLOBALLY HERE!` ?

Comment: @suraj The `AngularFireModule.init` initializes Firebase and the `AngularFireAuthModule` imports the authentication.  That's what I'm to understand, at least.

Comment: There is a typo in your `AuthService`:  `angularFire2/auth`  should be `angularfire2/auth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't see any differences between your code and the example code in the [`AngularFire2`-repo](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic3-Angular4.md) except for the typo in your `import`-statement in `AuthService`:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularFire2/auth';
```

which should be:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
```

The path is case-sensitive and your typo does break your code.

Comment: Unbelievable. I checked this so many times and overlooked it every time.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: We've all been there! :) Glad I could help!